# How do I update R code from nest_legacy to nest?

Tags: r, tidyr, purrr

I've got code (below) that applies a linear model in one quarter based on data from the previous quarter to estimate missing data, which works.

```
data <- data %>%
  nest_legacy(-groupvar1, -groupvar2) %>%
  mutate(modelvar1 = map(data, ~lm(var1 ~ quarter_date, data = .)),
         modelvar2 = map(data, ~lm(var2 ~ quarter_date, data = .)),
         var1_pred = map2(modelvar1, data, predict),
         var2_pred = map2(modelvar2, data, predict)) %>%
  select(-modelvar1, -modelvar2) %>%
  unnest_legacy()
```

I want to future proof it by using the new code for nest. I've followed the guidelines on the help page, and come up with the below:

```
data = data %>%
    nest(data = c(groupvar1, groupvar2)) %>%
    mutate(modelvar1 = map(data, ~lm(var1 ~ quarter_date, data = .)),
           modelvar2 = map(data, ~lm(var2 ~ quarter_date, data = .)),
           var1_pred = map2(modelvar1, data, predict),
           var2_pred = map2(modelvar2, data, predict)) %>%
    select(-modelvar1, -modelvar2) %>%
    unnest(data, cols = c(var1, var2))
```

However, I consistently get an error that

> Error: Column `c(aasb, tobd)` must be length 701 (the number of rows) or one, not 1402

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is. Can anyone please provide some insight? Thanks!

Edit: here's hopefully an example that might help.

```
quarter_date = as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-04-01"))
groupvar1 = c("spec1", "spec2", "spec1", "spec3", "spec3")
groupvar2 = c("loc1", "loc2", "loc3", "loc2", "loc3")
var1 = c(0, 656, 268, 78, 92)
var2 = c(87789, 45678, 23367, 76573, 68786)
test = tibble(groupvar1, groupvar2, var1, var2, quarter_date)
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your example data so that the original linear model code would work by formatting the dates and adding the quarter_date column to the final tibble

```
quarter_date = as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-07-01", "2014-04-01"))
groupvar1 = c("spec1", "spec2", "spec1", "spec3", "spec3")
groupvar2 = c("loc1", "loc2", "loc3", "loc2", "loc3")
var1 = c(0, 656, 268, 78, 92)
var2 = c(87789, 45678, 23367, 76573, 68786)
data = tibble(groupvar1, groupvar2, var1, var2, quarter_date)
```

To get the same output with the new `nest` you need a minus before the grouping variables, like you did in the original, and don't need a cols argument to unnest

```
data = data %>%
    nest(data = c(-groupvar1, -groupvar2)) %>%
    mutate(modelvar1 = map(data, ~lm(var1 ~ quarter_date, data = .)),
           modelvar2 = map(data, ~lm(var2 ~ quarter_date, data = .)),
           var1_pred = map2(modelvar1, data, predict),
           var2_pred = map2(modelvar2, data, predict)) %>%
    select(-modelvar1, -modelvar2) %>%
    unnest(data)
```